# how can i retrieve records from mongodb using Mongoose having non-empty array?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

```
 const records = await this.studentModel
      .find(
        { marks: { $exists: true, $not: { $size: 0 } } },
      )
```

**marks** is an array in Student schema, but using the above query i am getting records with empty array as well. can somebody help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the first element in the array exists or not

```
 const records = await this.studentModel
      .find(
        { "marks.0": { $exists: true } },
      )
```

Comment: not working, still getting records with empty array. do you have another way to query this?